# VS 10 includes, and I have a linker error

Tags: visual-c++, visual-c++-2010

I am using Visual Studio 10 to program in C++

The 1st part of my program is
//Includes

```
//#include <LEDA\numbers>               //fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'LEDA\numbers': No such file or directory

#include <LEDA/numbers/real.h>      
//Why do I get a linker error here
//All.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class leda::memory_manager leda::std_memory_mgr" (?std_memory_mgr@leda@@3Vmemory_manager@1@A)
#include <LEDA\numbers\integer.h>       //Here I used the system to write most of it for me
#include <LEDA/numbers/integer.h>            //Include LEDA. So 2 things 
        //1. including the same file twice does not matter
        //2. forward slashes and backward slashes are the same
      //I tried to use a wild card and said   #include <LEDA/numbers/*>  
      //But that did not work

 #include <LEDA/numbers/rational.h>
 #include <LEDA/core/string.h>
 #include <LEDA/core/array.h>
 #include <LEDA/numbers/bigfloat.h>  

      //The sqrt does not work


 #include <iostream>                          //include ordinary C++
 #include <math.h>
```

and I have a LINKER error

I have tried specifying which libraries to use by specifying the LIB User Environment symbol

I have tried specifying which libraries to use by specifying the
 Include Directories and
 Library Directories

in the properties of my Project

I have made a mistake somewhere, BUT where is it

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes in this program:

1. LEDA\numbers is apparently a directory, not an include file. So you shouldn't try to include it.
2. (conceptual) #include statements don't help in resolving linker errors at all. Instead, you need to specify the libraries you want to link with to the linker; libraries are files that end in .lib. Go to the project settings, and add the libraries containing the missing symbols.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <abcd.h> // looks for the include abcd.h in the INCLUDES path.

#include "abcd.h" // looks for the include abcd.h in the current path and then INCLUDES path.
```

From your description it looks like your LEDA lib in under your current directory. Try using "" instead of <> and see if it fixes your errors.